# Pass Perl array to bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, perl, soap

I am attempting to connect to the Footprints API using a Perl script. I am using Perl because that's one of the few languages the Footprints API will work with.

I want this Perl script to gather the data from Footprints, place the data in an array, and pass that array back to the shell script which calls it.

How do I pass an array from a Perl script to a bash script?

Below is the template for connecting to the Footprints API and collecting the data.

Template:

```
use strict;

use SOAP::Lite;

my $USE_PROXY_SERVER = 1;

my $soap = new SOAP::Lite;

$soap->uri( 'http://fakeserver.phoneycompany.com/MRWebServices' );

if ( $USE_PROXY_SERVER ) {
    $soap->proxy(
        'http://fakeserver.phoneycompany.com/MRcgi/MRWebServices.pl',
        proxy => ['http' => 'http://localhost:8888/'] );
}
else {
    $soap->proxy( 'http://fakeserver.phoneycompany.com/MRcgi/MRWebServices.pl' );
}

my $soapenv = $soap->MRWebServices__search(
    'WebServices',
    'fakepassword',
    '',
    "select mrID, mrTITLE from MASTER78 WHERE mrTITLE LIKE '%of%'"
);

my $result;

if ( $soapenv->fault ) {
    print ${$soapenv->fault}{faultstring} . "\n";
    exit;
}
else {
    $result = $soapenv->result;
}

my @result_list = @{$result};

for ( my $i = 0; $i <= $#result_list; $i++ ) {

    print "RESULT $i\n";

    my $hash_ref = $result_list[$i]; 

    foreach my $item ( keys %{$hash_ref} ) {
        my $val = $hash_ref->{$item};
        print "$item = '$val'\n";
    }

    print "---------------------\n";
}
```

In the template, I think it is just printing the key/value pairs to stdout.

I am new to Perl and am only using it to search the Footprints API. I'm not sure if you can somehow capture that data from stdout with the bash script, or if I have to do make an array or a string representation of the array and return that.

In my bash script, I was going to assign the result of the Perl script to a variable like `VAR=(perl perl_script.pl)`. But I don't know how to do that for an array, which was why I was thinking about the string representation of the array, assigning it to a variable and parsing it in bash afterwards.

I don't know how to set that up in Perl though, so I need help with that.

Comment: Why use bash at all if you have the power of Perl available?

Comment: Just because I don't know Perl and I know Bash, but I am beginning to think it'll work better if I just teach myself some basics and try it out

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is - you can't pass data structures between programs.

You can just pass text (and binary content, but I'd suggest you don't want to do that here).

One of the easiest ways of doing that is using an existing data interchange format, like JSON:

```
use JSON;
print to_json(\@result_list);
```

And then decode the JSON form *within* your bash script, manually.

Or just y'know, do all the work in `perl`. It's not that different.

Answer (score 0):

While, in general, and probably in this specific case, I would go with the "do it all in X" where X is anything more advanced than the shell, I have had to do this once or twice.  Mostly because I was setting up an interactive shell environment.

What I ended up doing is the same thing that tools like [`ssh-agent -s`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) do: building the shell commands that would result in the environment being set as desired, and then having the parent shell eval them, e.g.:

`eval $(perl perl_script.pl)`

Just watch out to ensure every separate command is separated by `;` since `\n`'s are (usually) squashed.

Another alternative, which I like a fair bit less, but I've used when generating variables for Windows' batch files, is to output the same to a new file and allow the parent batch file to `call` it (or, in shell, `source` it).  I'm not a big fan of temporary files if I can avoid them though it can make debugging a fair bit easier.